# How to echo corresponding value two when echoing value one?

Tags: php, foreach, echo

This is what I'd like to do:

1) check if `$title` contains any duplicates, if so only echo one and add to the `$number`
2) echo the `$counter`, `$title`, `$checkers` (these are hyperlinks) and `$number` (number of occurrences).

I'm struggling to echo the matching hyperlink `$checkers` for each echoed title

```
array(1) {
[0]=> Apples
[1]=> http://blah.com
}
array(2) {
[0]=> Bananas
[1]=> http://blahblah.com
}
array(3) {
[0]=> Apples
[1]=> http://blah.com
}
```

And then I'd like to echo:

1 => Apples => 2 => http://blah.com

1 => Bananas => 1 => http://blahblah.com

My code so far, but this just echoes one url... over and over again.

```
    $hyperArray[] = array($title, $href);
    $hyperTitle = array();

    foreach($hyperArray as $check){
        $hyperTitle[$check[0]] = (!isset($hyperTitle[$check[0]])) ? 1 : $hyperTitle[$check[0]] +1;

        $checkers = $check[1];
    //  echo '<pre>';
    //  var_dump($hyperArray);
    //  echo '</pre>';
    }

    $count = 0;
    foreach ( $hyperTitle as $hyperTitles => $number ){
        if ($hyperTitles){
        echo "{$count} => {$hyperTitles} => {$number} => {$check[1]} <br><br>\n";
        $count++;
    }}
```

UPDATE:

@Yogesh really helped me with his code. I just had to make a couple of changes including a counter and that's now doing exactly what I want it to do. Thanks!

```
$titleArray = array_column($hyperArray, 0);
$titleArray = array_count_values($titleArray);
$count = 1;
foreach ($hyperArray as $row) {
if (isset($titleArray[$row[0]])) {
    echo ($count) .' => '. $row[0].' => '. $titleArray[$row[0]] .' => 
'.$row[1] . "<br><br>";
    unset($titleArray[$row[0]]);
    $count++;
}
}
```

Comment: what is values for $title, $href?

Comment: `$href = $link->getAttribute('href');`
`$title = $link->nodeValue;` these all return the right values

Comment: You echo `$check[1]` all the time, but $check is not set anywhere in the loop that echoes, so it's just the same value over and over again.

Comment: Btw, why do you have an array named `$hyperTitle`, and then refer to the key of a single item with `$hyperTitles`? I think if you would sort out the naming, it might actually make things way more clear for you, let alone for us.

Comment: Value of $hyperArray is
array(array('Apples', 'http://blah.com'), array('Bananas', 'http://blahblah.com'), array('Apples', 'http://blah.com')) ?

Comment: @GolezTrol good point - very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @YogeshSalvi correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would solve your problem, I tried with single for loop instead of two:

```
$hyperArray = array(array('Apples', 'http://blah.com'), array('Bananas', 'http://blahblah.com'), array('Apples', 'http://blah.com'));
$titleArray = array_column($hyperArray, 0);
$titleArray = array_count_values($titleArray);
foreach ($hyperArray as $index=>$row) {
    if (array_key_exists($row[0], $titleArray)) {
        echo ($index+1) .' => '. $row[0].' => '. $titleArray[$row[0]] .' => '.$row[1]. PHP_EOL;
        unset($titleArray[$row[0]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Remco, check this one.

Comment: Thanks, It echoes the right hyperlinks, but now its missing the "only echo title once" so I'll have t try and fix that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: whilst it solved one - it created another,  so don't think I should accept the answer. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and let me know it works or not

```
$hyperArray[] = array($title, $href);

$hyperTitle = array(); // initialize
foreach($hyperArray as $check){
   if ( in_array($check[0], $hyperTitle) ) {
      $hyperTitle[$check[0]] = $hyperTitle[$check[0]] + 1;
   } else {
      $hyperTitle[$check[0]] = 1; // default value
   }
}

$count = 1;
foreach ( $hyperTitle as $hyperTitles => $number ){
  echo "{$count} => {$hyperTitles} => {$number} => {$check[1]} <br><br>\n"; // in this line you need get the value for $check[1]
  $count++;
}
```

Comment: that just echoes the same hyperlink.